# Confusion about Circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, conductors

I have two questions:

1. When dealing with simple DC circuits, it is often said that the electrons in the wire move because the charge density of the surface charges decreases. Is that due to the fact that the amount of electric field of the battery decreases with distance?
2. I don't understand why the potential difference between any two points in a wire is equal. It would make sense to me when the decrease rate (or gradient) in surface charge density would be the same in every point. But I just don't see why this should be the case. I couldn't find any explanation...

I would be very glad, If one could help me with my confusion :)

Comment: For 2), do you accept an answer based on Ohm's law?

Comment: Possibly useful: "A unified treatment of electrostatics and circuits" by Sherwood and Chabay https://matterandinteractions.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/circuit.pdf

Comment: I would say that both a) and b) are false. A) because the surface charge distribution can be very complicated and depends on the shape of the circuit and what is near to it. B) because in real life the wires have a finite conductivity, and this resolves the 0/0 conundrum without involving superconductors. Where did you find those statements?

Comment: Thanks to @robphy for the text. That was extremely helpful! I have understood now how the surface charges are build up. But still I haven't really understood why the electric field that comes from this surface charges is the same everywhere in the circuit. Can you help me how to imagine that there has to be a steady-state (or an equilibrium of field) after some time. I mean somehow this makes sense but I feel like It would help you could verbalize it to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you divide the wire into small segments, as you go from the positive to the negative terminals of the source, at each segment charge concentration decreases from a maximum at the positive terminal.

Let's say at the positive terminal the charge is 100 units. And the next segment it might be 99, then 98 and so on.

This makes the E fields constant between segments, and the voltage drop (E * segment length) the same at every segment also.

If like in this example there are 100 segments, the voltage drop across each is 1%, until you lose the entire voltage back at the negative terminal of the DC source.

If there is a resistor along the way, then for the segment with the resistor, you'd have such charge concentration between its ends as to result in the higher voltage gap necessary to maintain the same current through the resistor as through all the other segments. That's why resistors capture more of the voltage. (To see this clearly, we can picture the charge as located on segments, and the resistor would span the boundary between two subsequent segments. Thus the charge gap in the segments between which the resistor is nested would determine the current through the resistor.)

In the model when everything is a short circuit except the resistor, the charge concentrations in all the segments prior to the resistor are the same as at the positive terminal of the voltage source, resulting in no E and no voltage change prior to the resistor. Then at the resistor the charge gap expands all the voltage to pass the current. After the resistor there is again no difference in charge concentration between segments and hence no potential difference (no E fields) until the negative terminal of the DC source.

It's important to note: the current doesn't change that surface charge distribution because the current entering a segment or a ring of wire equals to the current leaving the same segment or a ring of wire. The E field is the result of different surface charge concentrations between subsequent segments or rings, and these remain constant as long as the DC sources voltage is constant.

The "static" surface charge distribution is then produced quickly as DC voltage is applied, and current flow is superimposed on top of it.

To address a comment: "But you assume that the charge distribution decreases uniformly (100,99,98,... in your example). And my question is, why is that so?"?

Let's say that after the quick redistribution of static surface charge (it takes about a nano second to achieve that static redistribution after the DC source is connected), there is a greater voltage between segments 20 to 21 than between segments 19 to 20 (while these segments are of the same resistance). In that case, very briefly, more charge will flow into segment 21 (20 --> 21) then enter segment 20 (19 --> 20). In the new redistribution, subsequent rings of the same resistivity will have the same gap\difference in surface charge concentration.

Only, it's important again to note, that this static surface charge is constant after about a nano second (provided the DC voltage is constant), and only on **top** of it, current flows. The current is enabled by the static surface charge distribution, but doesn't change it - the same current is entering and leaving each segment.

Thus in the example of disbanded between 19 --> 20 --> 21, the movement was not the final current but only a quick redistribution of surface charges. On top of the resulting static distribution (takes a nanosecond for everyday wires) current will flow uniformly.

PS
For segments of different resistance the logic is the same. A resistor requires a greater static surface charge gap between its ends, as otherwise the current entering the resistor will be more than the current leaving it, increasing the voltage gap across the resistor until equilibrium is reached. At equilibrium, the same current is entering and leaving the resistor, such that the surface charge concentration remains undisturbed by the uniform DC current flowing on top of (superimposed on top of) the static surface charge distribution.

Comment: But you assume that the charge distribution decreases uniformly (100,99,98,... in your example). And my question is, why is that so?

Comment: Because when E-field in the wire is equal everywhere und E-field is the result of different surface charge concentrations, then the difference in surface charge concentration should be the same everywhere, right? But I just don't get why?

Comment: I've tried to address the question. I recommend chapter 27 of "Physics
for scientists and engineers a strategic approach 4/e" by Randall Knight. He discusses the question you're asking in detail. In brief, the reason those static "surface charges" are the same everywhere (for segments of equal resistance) is that if they weren't charge movement would result until they're equal. On top of these current static surface charges, the final DC current flows.

Comment: A quote from the textbook: "A nonuniform distribution of surface charges along a wire creates a net electric field inside the wire that points from the more positive end of the wire toward the more negative end of the wire. This is the internal electric field E that pushes the electron current through the wire.
Note that the surface charges are not the moving charges of the current."

Sometimes the more "basic" resources turn out to be the best...

Comment: Okay thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately I can find no free access to the book you mentioned :(

Comment: Hope that helps - I also added a small additional bit about the resistor just now. I may be wrong of course, but I do believe the idea is correct, and it has a nice explanatory power to it, and the textbook says the same as far as I understand it. The limit of this model is the voltage at a segment seems to be determined  only by the charge between the two "rings" bordering a segment and not by all the other rings before and after. But it may be Ok, because E field significantly decreases with distance.

Comment: Last question: You mentioned: " there is a greater voltage between segments 20 to 21 than between segments 19 to 20 (while these segments are of the same resistance). In that case, very briefly, more charge will flow into segment 21 (20 --> 21) then enter segment 20 (19 --> 20)." I was asking myself if it could happen that after this rearrangement the surface charge distribution could be equally distributed in every segment. This would be bad, because there would be no E.field. How is that avoided?

Comment: Yes, if 19, 20 and 21 had the same charge distribution then indeed there would be no E field (a short circuit part of the wire). The key is that seg. 19 to 20 may have E field of 3 and V of 5. And seg. 20 to 21 may have E field of 3 and V of 5. In this case current is the same between 19 to 20 and 20 to 21 (5 / Segment Resistance). Hence no more current would enter segment 20 than leave it, but there is an E field 19 to 20 and between 20 and 21. The surface charges create a downfall gradient of E, leading to the same current in equilibrium (between segments), but that E doesn't have to be zero

Comment: The equilibrium E between one segment and the next would allow the same current through the segment as through every other segment, and the surface charges would arrange accordingly (more charge can be stored at segment 19 than at segment 20, leading to E and current in between - as long as the resulting current is the same between 19 and 20, as between every other two segments, uniform current will flow on top of the surface distribution (and not alter it, because the current leaving one segment just matches the current entering the same segment).

Comment: Notice that in this model charge lives on a segment, but E and V and current are between one segment and the next. Segment 19 has charge 10, segment 20 has charge 9, there is some E and V between the two segments. And current flows per the inter-segment resistance V / (resistance between 19 and 20). At equilibrium the charges living on each segment arrange such that no more current would leave a particular segment to the next segment than enter the same segment from the preceding one.

Answer (score 4):

We often model a wire as an object where the potential difference between any two points is zero. This is a useful simplification for many problems. If wire resistance is important, we use Ohm's law to relate current to potential difference.

We don't normally, when modeling DC circuits, consider the surface charge density, since this depends on unimportant details of how the wires are arranged geometrically and is difficult to compute. Instead, we use potentials, currents, and Ohm's law.

Answer (score 3):

I will resort to the water analogy to make things easier to understand.

1. A river flows because there is a slight height gradient in riverbed. The water starts out at a high point and flows towards a low point. The height of the water is here the potential. In equilibrium, for a constant slope river bed, this will have constant gradient (see picture below). The velocity of the water will be proportional to the slope, again, in equilibrium. Since the slope is constant, the velocity of the water will be constant as well.

To translate this to an electric potential is easy. The height will become the potential, and the water velocity becomes the current. The electric field will be roughly constant along the wire. Note that in electrical wires there are surface effects as well, as you mentioned, so consider this diagram below as a simplification.

2. In a real wire this is simply not true. The wire has a finite resistance, so there is a finite voltage drop over any piece of wire. It is an often made simplification to consider a wire as 'ideal', which has zero resistance anywhere. The resistance in a wire is often neglible compared to other resistances. If the resistance of a particular is *not* neglible compared to some other component, you can simply draw the wire as a resistor in series with that component, connected by ideal wires.

[image]